# c3p0 getConnection() throws exception: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling, c3p0

We have a [Hibernate + c3p0 + MySQL] config for our project. We are hitting the following exception:

```
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
Wrapped by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
Wrapped by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1263) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:399) ~[spring-orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
Wrapped by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:440) ~[spring-orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371) ~[spring-tx-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:336) ~[spring-tx-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105) ~[spring-tx-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) ~[spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy28.messageExists(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Our c3p0 config:

```
<bean id="provDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
…
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="100"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="1800" />
</bean>
```

Note that we also have another similar c3p0 datasource configured on top of this MySQL instance.

Can anyone give me some suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: what does the other datasource look like?

Comment: Same config with different id.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the connection limit on the database?

Comment: Also does this happen on start up or after a while at run time? Are you sure you've configured your database settings correctly?

Comment: This is during run time. I doubt it was related to the connection limit for the db. The monitor shows the DB connection count with a sawtooth pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave), which is really weird. The DB is getting from anywhere between 40-300 connections. We have ds1 with maxPoolSize=300 and ds2 with maxPoolSize=50.

Comment: so whats the limit on the DB?

Comment: 1200 is the limit. We are far from there. BTW, the sawtooth problem was identified. We have a script that opens connections without closing them. That is now fixed. But this should have nothing to do with the getConnection() problem here.

Comment: Have you noticed any pattern to this exception occuring? Does it occur on both datasources? Have you debugged before getting the connection to see if the datasource is in a weird state when it throws the exception?

Comment: Are you able to bump up the logging level on C3PO?

Comment: @Brian No pattern has been recognized. It happens on both ds. We are not able to reproduce the problem. So not possible to debug.

Comment: @Alex How do I bump up the logging level in c3p0? We are using logback, btw.

Comment: But how often does it happen and how soon after start up?

Comment: @Brian There is no pattern for it.

Comment: Looks like c3p0 is hard-wired to use log4j (http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_logging). Your best bet is probably to install the log4j-over-slf4j bridge (http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) and then modify your logback configuration to increase the logging level of the com.mchange appender.

Comment: You're going to need to explain exactly what happens. Does it happen every time hibernate attempts to make a connection? I think you need to include your session factory bean and also the hibernate calling code

Answer (score 0):

Although not strictly answering your question, I didn't want to add code in the comments as code in comments is unreadable.

Here is an example config of MySQL with C3P0 from my project. note all the extra parameters to make sure the connections don't die. (In the end I went with Postgres because it didn't kill my connections and was more stable generally, also having to retest connections with select 1; isn't very efficient)

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
     destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
  <property name="properties">
    <props>
        <prop key="c3p0.minPoolSize">0</prop>
        <prop key="hc3p0.maxPoolSize">1000</prop>
        <prop key="hc3p0.timeout">3000</prop>
        <prop key="c3p0.acquire_increment">10</prop>
        <prop key="c3p0.max_statement">50</prop>

        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">60</prop>
        <prop key="c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1;</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</prop>
        <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop>
        <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following list of causes and resolutions which helped me solve the problem. Might also help others:

1. **The database configuration details you entered are incorrect or have changed**. For example, the database name or database username/password for your Confluence database. Confirm that the database username, password, and connection URL in /confluence.cfg.xml are incorrect, and if not update them accordingly.
2. **The URL for the database is incorrect**. For example, if the database connection is jdbc:mysql://yma/confluence?autoReconnect=true, does the host 'yma' exist and is the database server installed on 'yma'? Check /confluence.cfg.xml to find this entry.
3. **The database server is not running**. If your database server is down, restart it and check the logs to see why it had failed or stopped.
4. **The network is down** (or there is a firewall in between Confluence and its database) and the connection to the database cannot be established. If your network is down, or a new firewall is installed, consult with your System Administrator for further troubleshooting.
5. **Your database password has expired.** If your password has expired (and you will only discover this if you try to connect to your database via your database client or an external database tool such as DbVisualizer), update your password. You may want to deactivate expiring passwords for your Confluence database user to prevent the problem from happening again. Be sure to consult with your DBA about this.
6. **Postgres specific issue**: the Postgres encryption method has been altered or changed when migrating or upgrading Confluence, the environment, etc. Check the pg_hba.conf file. If the method is set to ident change it to md5.
7. **MySQL specific issue**: there are too many connection requests that triggered MySQL server to block Confluence from making any requests. See this MySQL article for resolution.

Source: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/connections-could-not-be-acquired-from-the-underlying-database-104825087.html